# Getting system information in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently designing a website to know if staffs of an organization are at work using is there a way i can get the user system information like MAC address if that wont change about the system, i have seen a lot of mac addresses code but none works, would be grateful if i get ideas on how to go about doing this. thanks guys..
this is 1 of what ihave tried

```
echo GetMAC();

function GetMAC(){
    ob_start();
    system('getmac');
    $Content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
    return substr($Content, strpos($Content,'\\')-20, 17);
}
```

Comment: How would a PHP Script that runs on a server get thr mac id of the network adapter?

Comment: those where suggestion of others thats why i sed those where the codes i get and decided to try them but they don't work so if there is any method please i would be glad to here how, thanks

Answer (score 3):

basically, you can't.
The MAC address is not broadcast beyond the LAN the device is connected to - its locked in the internal network and never leaves the router and passes to the server.

But in theory you can get it in Javascript since that runs on the Client, but it's not going to work without the permition of the client except in exceptional circumstances. 
You can use an ActiveX control to get the MAC, and they only run under IE, and most systems default to "don't run ActiveX controls" to prevent all sorts of security problems like get personal information about the pc, OS or in your case the Mac address.

In php you can normally get the mac but its the mac address of the network card of the server and in most cases of some router that provide the connection to the internet.

Hope is clear for you and helps you understand.

Comment: thanks but using the  ActiveX control do you have any documentation on how to do that

Comment: Not exactly but here is a good source and some documentation: https://techdetails.agwego.com/2008/02/11/37/

Comment: ActiveX is a potential security threat. And a MAC address can be changed easily. Have you had a look on evercookie? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie - You could save an UUID and store it into a super/evercookie instead.